# The item provided did not have an id

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

Please help me , while calling update script for a table in azure I always got the error

> The item provided did not have an id

and when I added the id of the row to the dictionary then comes a new error

> ERROR Error
>   Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1105
>    The item provided did not have a valid id.
>
> UserInfo=0x1d587e20 {NSLocalizedDescription=The item provided did not
>   have a valid id.}

How should i update the entry ?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to insert the item? Also, which version of the iOS Mobile Services SDK are you using?

Comment: -(void)updateCompanyTPersonTable:(NSDictionary*)item tableName:(NSString *)tableName{
    NSLog(@"updateCompanyTPersonTable");
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"table": tableName};
    
    [self.jobagg_companyTPersonTable update: item parameters:params completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error){
        
        [self logErrorIfNotNil:error];
        
       // completion();
        
    }];
}
This is the function I am using to call update script , I am using ios sdk 7.0

Comment: What is the value of the id in the `item` dictionary you're trying to update? If you add a `NSLog(@"id: %@", [item objectForKey:@"id"])` to your method it should tell you that value.

Answer (score 0):

Every table in an azure mobile service has an ID field. You must include the ID field when posting an update. The ID field only has to be in the class not the actual data you are sending for example.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}


CurrentPlatform.Init();
Item item = new Item { Text = "Awesome item" };
await App

Delegate.MobileService.GetTable<Item>().InsertAsync(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the last Windows Azure SDK